# How to get latitude and longitude values from Cell Id in android?

Tags: android, location

I am developing a android application in that i want find the user location using GPS. That is working fine .But if the GPS is Disabled means i want to find the user location based on the CellID and Loc .It is possible or not

It is possible means please tell me how to do that with sample code

Waiting for reply

Comment: Accept correct answers to the questions you post - and you'll most likely get quicker and better answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40524/1954) is complete tutorial of **Location-Based Services Using CellID in Android**.

Answer (score 1):

Just request the "best" location provider, and you'll either get the GPS if it's available or the network (wifi / cell) if it's not.

[LocationManager.getBestProvider()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#getBestProvider(android.location.Criteria,%20boolean))

You don't need to explicitly code to either GPS / network providers.